# Infix to prefix of expression using javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tree, prefix

How to convert below infix to prefix .

`((e.source = a.id)AND (e.target=b.id) AND ( NOT(a.color != blue) OR ( b.age<= 23 )))`

I tried some thing , firstly I converted into simple variable

```
Step 1 :  ((X)AND(Y) AND (NOT (E) OR (T)))
Step 2 :  ((X)AND(Y) AND (NOT  OR ET ))
Step 3 :  (AND XY AND (NOT OR ET))
Step 4 :  (AND AND XY (NOT OR ET ))
```

Then finally X,Y,E and T I replace with actual expression putting equal to on front

Final Answer :  `AND AND = e.source a.id = e.target b.id NOT OR != a.color blue <= b.age 23`

Have I done it correctly . I have to program it also how to approach this  problem in JavaScript.

Comment: do you have a tokenizer?

Comment: I have expression only , I need to convert to prefix and also prefix to postfix retaining brackets @NinaScholz

Comment: What you have done seems correct! For implementation, I would assume you approach it the same way as you would normally - using operand and operator stacks